# Disabling and Reenabling Draggable on Class

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I am trying to toggle draggable on a class, and it works fine initially but the second time you try to enable the class with draggable (Enable->Disable->Enable), it doesnt seem to work. I have set up a jsfiddle to illustrate my concept. Essentially, I just want my draggable elements to be reenabled the second time around.

http://jsfiddle.net/3XZAd/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing in an object with `disabled` property set to `true` or `false`:

```
// when button clicked ...
$('#enable').click(function() {
    // also enable li tag with id test1
    $('.tests').draggable({disabled: false});
});
// when button clicked ...
$('#disable').click(function() {
    // also enable li tag with id test1
    $('.tests').draggable({disabled: true});
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3XZAd/4/)

Answer (score 4):

You have to set explicitly the "disabled" option to true or false:

http://jsfiddle.net/v22Ef/

Comment: But your response is more verbose ;)